# Nginx custom fastcgi_param variable visible from browser but invisible from console command

Tags: php, nginx

**Nginx** custom **fastcgi_param** variable is visible from the Web browser but invisible from the console command.

```
fastcgi_param CUSTOM_VARIABLE "custom_variable_value";
```

Web browser (PHP):

```
var_dump(env('CUSTOM_VARIABLE')); // Return "custom_variable_value";
var_dump(getenv('CUSTOM_VARIABLE')); // Return "custom_variable_value";
var_dump($_SERVER['CUSTOM_VARIABLE']); // Return "custom_variable_value";
```

Console command (PHP):

```
var_dump(env('CUSTOM_VARIABLE')); // Return error "Unknown or undefined key" or NULL;
var_dump(getenv('CUSTOM_VARIABLE')); // Return error "Unknown or undefined key" or NULL;
var_dump($_SERVER['CUSTOM_VARIABLE']); // Return error "Unknown or undefined key" or NULL;
```

How to make fastcgi_param CUSTOM_VARIABLE visible for the console command?

Comment: The console command doesn't go through nginx, it goes directly through the php executable.